# Why is the nitrile nitrogen sp hybridized?

Tags: hybridization, valence-bond-theory

[image]

This [site](http://www.meta-synthesis.com/webbook/40_polyatomics/polyatomics.html), from which the above image was taken, indicates that the hybridization of the orbitals on the C and N atoms in hydrogen cyanide is sp. I can certainly see how that would be the case for carbon, but why need the terminal nitrogen atom have sp hybrid orbitals? Couldn't it form a σ bond with the carbon's sp orbital through its s or p orbitals and use two other p orbitals to form the two π bonds?

Comment: Where do the "lone pair" electrons end up in such scenario? Do they move into the s orbital and orbit closer to the N nucleus, or do they occupy the p orbital and spend some time between the carbon and the nitrogen?

Comment: @Max I'm not sure what you're getting at, but I'd say the former.